# React DrawerNavigation Is Not Working (Nothing Happens) While I Drag To Open Side Menu

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to introduce DrawerNavigation under StackNavigation. **My StackNavigation is working fine. But when I'm dragging the screen DrawerNavigation is not working.** Nothing happens...No errors also.

I am using TouchableOpacity for the list items. Though I don't think so, is there any chance it is occurring due to the first touch on list-item??? If not, then can anyone point me out what the issue is? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

I have given my **Navigator.Js code** here and a **video Url** to understand better what is happening for my case.

[image: Navigation.js]

**Video URL -** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MhD3gB8Pp4tqbXr1HktOPa-2xOqW0xoA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of wrapping `DrawerNavigator` inside `StackNavigator`, wrap your `StackNavigator` inside `DrawerNavigator`.

**Working Example:** [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/spunky-pastry)

**Output:**

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const StackNav = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={() => <Text>Login</Text>} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={() => <Text>Register</Text>} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Stack" component={StackNav} />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="HomeNews"
            component={() => (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>HomeNews</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />
          <Drawer.Screen
            name="StateNews"
            component={() => (
              <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text>StateNews</Text>
              </View>
            )}
          />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
});
```